# Getting current Year and Month resulting strange results

Tags: java, android, date, gregorian-calendar

I am working on a learning project related to Android. I am trying to get current year & month by using below code but it not works for me.

```
GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
gc.YEAR // returning 1       
gc.MONTH // returning 2

Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.YEAR // returning 1       
c.MONTH // returning 2
```

Can someone help me? Am i doing something wrong? please forgive me i am new to java development. thanks.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Just to give a bit more background:

Both `new GregorianCalendar()` and `Calendar.getInstance()` will correctly give a calendar initialized at the current date and time.

`MONTH` and `YEAR` are *constants* within the [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class. You should *not* use them "via" a reference which makes it look like they're part of the state of an object. It's an unfortunate part of the design of the `Calendar` class that to access the values of different fields, you need to call `get` with a field number, specified as one of those constants, as shown in other answers:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
```

Note that the month numbers are 0-based, so at the time of this writing (in April) the month number will be 3.

It's an unfortunate part of the design of the Java language that you *can* reference static members (such as constants) via expressions of that type, rather than *only* through the type name.

My recommendations:

- If your IDE allows it (as Eclipse does), make expressions such as `c.YEAR` give a compile-time error - you'll end up with much clearer code if you always use `Calendar.YEAR`.
- Where possible, use [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) - a much better date/time library for Java. Admittedly on Android you may be a bit space-constrained, but if your app does a lot of date/time manipulation, it would save you a lot of headaches.

Comment: @YaqubAhmad: My pleasure - two of the other answers were *correct*, but I felt they could do with a bit more explanation :)

Answer (score 23):

Note MONTHS starts from 0..So if you need to map it to practical problems just add +1

```
int month=c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
```

Comment: int cmonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);//this is april so you will receive  3 instead of 4.

Comment: The person who voted down for my result...see this line in the accepted answer...to make it compatible with real month you must add 1..otherwise January will be 0...If u dono understand dont vote...don't -1

Comment: For sane numbering, use the modern approach with the *java.time* classes: `LocalDate.now().getMonthValue()` ➙ 1-12 for January-December.

Answer (score 5):

```
int year=c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month=c.get(Calendar.MONTH);

   System.out.println(year);
   System.out.println(month);
```

Comment: FYI, c.get(Calendar.MONTH) is a zero based index of the months.

Answer (score 4):

## tl;dr

```
YearMonth.now( 
    ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) 
)
```

## Details

The [Answer by Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10161805/642706) is correct. You were accessing constants rather than interrogating your own object.

Here is an entirely different alternative, using modern date-time classes.

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

The old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

## `YearMonth`

If you are focused on the year and month without a date, without a time-of-day, and without a time zone, use the [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) class.

Rather than pass mere integer numbers around for year and for month, pass around objects of this class. Doing so provides type-safety, ensures valid values, and makes your code more self-documenting.

Determining the current year and month means determining the current date. And for that a time zone is crucial. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.now( z );
```

You can interrogate for its parts.

```
int year = ym.getYear();
int month = ym.getMonthValue();
```

This class offers handy methods such as telling you if this is a leap year. You can do math, such as adding/subtracting months/years. You can get a date for any day of this year-month. And more.

## `Month`

Rather than mess around with a mere integer for month, I suggest you use the [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) enum. This class has a dozen instances pre-defined, one for each month of the year. As mentioned above, using objects gives you type-safety, valid values, and self-documenting code.

```
Month m = ym.getMonth();
```

The class has helpful methods such as generating an localized string with the month’s name.

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts ***ThreeTen-Backport*** (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 3):

```
Calendar c= Calendar.getInstance()
int cyear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);//calender year starts from 1900 so you must add 1900 to the value recevie.i.e., 1990+112 = 2012
int cmonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);//this is april so you will receive  3 instead of 4.
int cday = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

refer this [LINK](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html)

Answer (score 2):

#### How to get current Year and Month.

```
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();             
        int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
        int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

---

Very important to add 1 to get the correct month, because the first month value is 0:

```
        int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
```

> [**MONTH**](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH) :Field number for get and set indicating the month. This is a calendar-specific value. The first month of the year in the Gregorian and Julian calendars is JANUARY which is 0; the last depends on the number of months in a year.

Comment: This terrible Calendar class was supplanted years ago by the java.time classes with the adoption of JSR 310. The modern approach: `LocalDate.now().getMonthValue()`

Comment: @BasilBourque Call requires API level 26 (current min is 24): `java.time.LocalDate#now`

Comment: @ARSharifUddinJUMMAN Not quite the case any longer. For earlier versions of Android, you have access to some of the newer classes such as *java.time* via “desugaring” in the latest tooling. See the official article: [*Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table).

Comment: @ARSharifUddinJUMMAN change inside your Build,gradle: minSdkVersion 26

Comment: @BasilBourque Basically, I am designing my project in such a way that Android 7 users can also use it.
So I am currently getting date, month and year through Calendar class.